# hide a link if parent spans are empty?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide link from a cell if other elements in that cell are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332476/hide-link-from-a-cell-if-other-elements-in-that-cell-are-empty)

How to hide the 'map and directions' link if the parent spans have no value?? I want to hide the map and direction link if there is no office name, address, phone and working hours..like on the first cell there are all those values so i want the map and direction to show up but in the second one, since there are no values, the map and directions link should hide..how do u do it using jquery?

```
 <tr>                                     
    <td class="Office3" style="border-top:1px dotted silver;  width:40%;">
     <span class="OfficeName">
     St. Margaret Hospital<br />
     </span>
     <span class="Address">
     2001 86th Street West,  <br />Indianapolis, IN 46260 </span>
     <span class="Phone">
     (317) 342-1254</span><br />
     <a class="mapdirectionsLink" href="#">map &#38; directions&#62;</a><br /><br />
     <span class="Hours">
     MTW: 9:00 AM- 5:00 PM </span>
    </td>
    <td class="Office4" style="border-top:1px dotted silver;  width:40%">   
    <span class="OfficeName">
    &#160;<br />
    </span>
    <span class="Address">
    <div dir=""></div>&#160;</span>                                     
    <span class="Phone">
    &#160;</span><br />
    <a class="mapdirectionsLink" href="#">map &#38; directions&#62;</a><br /><br />
    <span class="Hours">
    &#160;</span>                       
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it hides the link no matter if the parent spans have text or not..$('a.mapdirectionsLink').each(function() { 
     if ($(this).prev('span').text() == '') { 
     $(this).hide(); 
    } 
 });

Comment: That's because the previous tag isn't a "span".  It's a "br".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your `<td>`s are in a table with class "offices":

```
$("table.offices td").filter(function () {
  return $(this).children("span").map(
    function () { return $.trim( $(this).text() ); }
  ).toArray().join("") == "";
}).find("a.mapdirectionsLink").hide();
```

Comment: If we forget about the table and just consider this, how would you hide the link? If anyone of these span is empty, hide the link??<span class="OfficeName"> 
     St. Margaret Hospital<br /> 
     </span> 
     <span class="Address"> 
     2001 86th Street West,  <br />Indianapolis, IN 46260 </span> 
     <span class="Phone"> 
     (317) 342-1254</span><br /> 
     <a class="mapdirectionsLink" href="#">map &#38; directions&#62;</a><br /><br /> 
     <span class="Hours"> 
     MTW: 9:00 AM- 5:00 PM </span>